# Как запустить job в Jenkins n-раз?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Возможно ли в Jenkins запустить job n-раз?

Я бы хотела написать скрипт в конфигурации (windows batch command / groovy) который позволит мне сделать это. В этом скрипте я бы хотела иметь массив с параметрами и запустить этот job с каждым из них в цикле. Это должно выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
paramArray [] = ["a","b", "c"];
for(int i=0; i < paramArray.length; i++)
{
  //Here I want to run this job with each parameter
    job.run(paramArray[i]);
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите написать правильный скрипт для этой цели.
Большое спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Проверенное pipeline-решение (groovy-скрипт), с комментариями:

```
// массив с параметрами
parameters = ["first", "second", "another one"]

def myJob(parameter)
{
    //действия вашего job'а:
    echo parameter
}

// блок node по-умолчанию будет выполнять скрипт на master'e
// если не указано имя машины
node(){
    // перебираем в цикле все значения нашего массива
    parameters.each{
        // значение каждого элемента массива доступно в переменной `it`
        stage(it){
            // вызываем job:
            myJob(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример на [Jenkins DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/README.md) с использованием [Pipeline: Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Build+Step+Plugin):

```
def params = ['a', 'b', 'c']

params.each { paramValue ->
    build(
        job: 'project/name',
        parameters: [
            string(
                name: 'PARAMETER', 
                value: paramValue
            )
        ],
        propagate: true,
        wait: true
    )
}
```

Чтобы воспользоваться подобным решением вам нужно создать job с параметром  типа `string` с именем `PARAMETER` (либо freestyle через опцию "This project is parameterized"), либо через pipeline:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(
            defaultValue: '', 
            description: '', 
            name: 'PARAMETER', 
            trim: true
        )
    ])
])
```

В самой job-е к параметру можно обращаться через переменную `$PARAMETER`.